# Is it possible to mock a static void method in powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

A class has a method inside which there are several calls of other class's static void methods.

i.e.

```
public class Foo()
{
 public void Bar()
{
  //some code
  OtherClass.callVoidMethod1();
 // some code
OtherClass.callVoidMethod2();
}
}
```

In my unit tests I need OtherClass.callVoidMethod2(); not to be called and was suggested to mock it.
But so far I can't find how to mock static void method call. Is it even possible?
Available in the project: mockito, powermock, testng.

Comment: Yes, it can. The answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585323/how-do-i-mock-a-static-method-that-returns-void-with-powermock . Of course, if you control the code, refactoring is better than fighting to symptoms of bad code with PowerMock ;-)

Comment: Ugh I thought there would be a way to do the 
when(callVoidMethod2()).then(doSomething)

Comment: No, the PowerMock syntax is something you need to get used to... Another reason why I prefer not to use it, instead opting to refactor code or introducing non-static objects that can be mocked (the real object calls the static method, so you can prevent that via a mock).

Comment: Unfortunately I am not supposed to refactor the class I'm testing but I did refactor my test so that I don't need Powermock there anymore. Whew such a relief )