# Mocking static method that returns void with PowerMock does not work

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I tried all the answers regarding similar questions but I couldn't make it work (like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9585323/999986))

I have this class (simplified)

```
public class ItemParametersParser
{ ...
  public static void writeToFile(Item i,  Context c, Builder b) throws HandlerException
}
```

I am trying to mock the writeToFile method with no success

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ItemParametersParser.class})
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws ... {        
        mockStatic(ItemParametersParser.class);
        doNothing().when(ItemParametersParser.class);
        ItemParametersParser.writeXMLToFile(null,null,null);
        ...
    }
```

This result with going to the original method
I tried also mock the specific method using:

```
doNothing().when(ItemParametersParser.writeXMLToFile(any(Item.class),any(Context.class),any(Builder.class)));
```

but I get this error for doNothing.when(...

> The method when(T) in the type Stubber is not applicable for the arguments (void)

or this error if I use PowerMokito.doNothing().when(...

> The method when(Class) in the type PowerMockitoStubber is not applicable for the arguments (void)

using doAnswer also didn't work

**Edit:**
After fixing the import issue, as mentioned by @pvpkiran, it works now! I could verify it using doAnswer.

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
      Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
      System.out.println("called with arguments: " + Arrays.toString(args));
          return null;
    }
}).when(ItemParametersParser.class, "writeToFile", any(Item.class), any(Context.class),any(Builder.class));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
 @Test
  public void test() throws .... {
    mockStatic(ItemParametersParser.class);
    doNothing().when(ItemParametersParser.class, "writeToFile", any(Item.class), any(Context.class),any(Builder.class));
  }
```

First argument is a class instance of the class under test, Second argument is the method name which you want to mock followed by arguments of the method.

Make sure you import `org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doNothing`  and not `org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing`

Comment: I've seen a similar solution before, however, I cannot pass arguments to "when". I get this error "The method when(T) in the type Stubber is not applicable for the arguments (Class<ItemParametersParser>, String, any(Item.class), any(Context.class), any(Builder.class))"

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me.  I believe you are using `import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;` . You should use `import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doNothing;`

Comment: hooray! the issue indeed was my imports. After changing the imports both solutions works.

Answer (score 3):

Your `when` method should be on object:

```
ItemParametersParser itemParametersParser= mock(ItemParametersParser.class);    
doNothing().when(itemParametersParser).writeXMLToFile(any(Item.class),any(Context.class),any(Builder.class));
```

Comment: It doesn't work with this error: "ItemParametersParser cannot be resolved to a variable". also if I create an "object" of this class it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to add `@Mock
    ItemParametersParser ItemParametersParser;`

Comment: It doesn't make any difference

Comment: The issue was my imports, as @pvpkiran mentioned. Your solution however still doesn't work for me. I get UnfinishedStubbingException. And also a warning that "ItemParametersParser should be accessed in a static way"