# How to PowerMockito.doNothing when a static method of a final class is called?

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito

I have this line of code in one of the utility class

```
System.setProperty("someProperty", <StringValue>);
```

**I want nothing to be happened, when the above line of code is executed through the tests.**
I have annotated the class with following annotations.

```
@PrepareForTest({KeyStore.class, System.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.security.*"})
```

I have tried to do nothing using following options:

```
1. PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
   PowerMockito.doNothing().when(System.class, "setProperty", "someProperty", "stringValue");

2. PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
   PowerMockito.doNothing().when(System.class, "setProperty", Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(String.class));

3. PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
   PowerMockito.doAnswer(new org.mockito.stubbing.Answer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return null; //does nothing
            }
        }).when(System.class, "setProperty", "someProperty", "stringValue");
```

I always get the following error on test execution.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
```

Any suggestions on how I can do nothing when System.setProperty is called.
Please note System is a final class, we are calling a static method with 2 arguments.
Thank you!!

Comment: Not sure but this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585323/how-do-i-mock-a-static-method-that-returns-void-with-powermock

Answer (score 0):

Only void methods can doNothing()!. `setProperty() returns String`

use

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
PowerMockito.when(System.setProperty(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("test");
```